# ng model not updating in radio button group with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am displaying radio buttons based on search result using ng-repeat.
if i select any radio button, its color will change.
actual issue is, when i do second search, list will replace with new list.
but when i select any radion button its color not changed.

**View:**

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 nl_item" ng-repeat="nomineeMgr in nomineesMgrList track by $index">
    <div class="checkbox" ng-class="{'blue1': nomineeMgr.SystemUserId===nomManagerSelectedId}">
     <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" value="" name="selectedNomineeMgr{{$index}}"
        ng-model="$parent.nomManagerSelectedId" ng-value="{{nomineeMgr.SystemUserId}}" />{{nomineeMgr.SystemUserId===nomManagerSelectedId?"SELECTED"}}
</label>
  </div>
    </div>
```

angular controller:

```
$scope.nomManagerSelectedId = 0;

 $scope.searchNomineesManager = function (isValid) {
        if (!isValid)
            return;
        var result = pepsicoService.getPepsicoEmployees($rootScope.UrlProvider.getPepsicoSearchEmployeesUrl, null, $scope.searchNomination.searchNomineMgr).then(function (response) {
            if (response.data.success) {               
                $scope.nomineesMgrList = [];
                $scope.nomManagerSelectedId = 0;

                $scope.nomineesMgrList = response.data.EmployeeList;


            }
            else {
                $rootScope.showFailureMsg(response.data.errorMessage);
            }
        });
    };
```

any one have an idea to solve this issue?

Comment: Working JSFiddle / Plunkr available?

Comment: You should be using `ng-value="nomineeMgr.SystemUserId"` instead of `ng-value="{{nomineeMgr.SystemUserId}}"`